# Superscript and subscript differentiation using pdf box

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am new to pdfbox Is there any way to differentiate superscript and subscript text from normal text when extracting or after extracting text from pdf using pdfbox library thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Check this link if this helps

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintTextLocations.java

Comment: While the linked page may give an answer to the question (and @Tilman's comment seems to indicate that), answers on stack overflow are expected to be more self-contained. Thus, please add the pivotal code from that link to your answer,

Answer (score 1):

Was able to identify most superscripts by looking for Y and Height changes. Try this:

Write your own implementation of PDFTextStripper.

Add this to `writePage()` to convert superscripts into separate words:

```
if((position.getY() < lastPosition.getTextPosition().getY()
    && position.getHeight() < lastPosition.getTextPosition().getHeight())
    || (position.getY() > lastPosition.getTextPosition().getY()
    && position.getHeight() > lastPosition.getTextPosition().getHeight()))
                    line.add(WordSeparator.getSeparator());
```

Then add this to writeLine() to add a tag before or after Superscripts:

```
        if(word.textPositions.size()>0)
        {
        TextPosition firstChar = word.textPositions.get(0);

        if(i==0)
        {
            prevY = firstChar.getY();
            prevHeight = firstChar.getHeight();
        }

        if(prevY!=0)
        {
        if((firstChar.getY() < prevY && firstChar.getHeight() < prevHeight))
        {
    output.write("<sup>");
    writeString(word.getText(), word.getTextPositions());

        }
        else if((firstChar.getY() > prevY && firstChar.getHeight() > prevHeight))
        {
             output.write("</sup>");
             writeString(word.getText(), word.getTextPositions());

        }
        else
            writeString(word.getText(), word.getTextPositions());
        }
```

Comment: I have fixed and extended the code. The original version would not put the <sup> if the superscript was at the beginning of the line, neither it would put </sup> if it was the last entry in the line. The implementation first scans the list of words and inserts the tags in the list of words and only then it prints out the words.