# Absolute positions in PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm writing a program that converts `TeX`-generated PDFs back to a `TeX`-like string of text. In order to achieve that I use `Apache PDFBox`.

I would like to be able to detect subscripts, superscripts and then use a `TeX`-like method to denote them. I have read this question: [Superscript and subscript differentiation using pdf box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700500/superscript-and-subscript-differentiation-using-pdf-box) which isn't really helpful because it is impossible to detect subscripts and superscripts using `Y` and `EndY` probably because they are relative. Is there any way to detect the absolute position of text? The height of a glyph is actually easy to obtain as long as people use old TeX fonts though so I can easily detect font size change.

Comment: Please explain why you think the **y** coordinates are relative because they should be absolute (in a specific coordinate system) in pdfbox. And even if they were relative, as long as you understood what they were relative to, they still could be of help.

Comment: Did you look at the DrawPrintTextLocations.java example? That one paints the positions. So they are absolute.